# Why does a RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} interfere with a second NOT condition?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

At first the rule that works:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
ErrorDocument 403 /form.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteRule . - [F,L]
```

This means `http://example.com` and `http://example.com/index.php` can only be opened through `POST`.

**Now the problem**

I added this additional rule set:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteRule . - [F,L]
```

Now, I send a POST again to `http://example.com` but receive this error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

This does not make sense, because the rule should NOT catch requests on `index.php` sending a 403, but ok, I extended the second rule as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/form\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
RewriteRule . - [F,L]
```

And sending again a POST to http://example.com returns no 500, but I still receive a 403?!

**Update 1**
If I remove the first rule set, the second one works alone as expected. This means only `http://example.com`, `http://example.com/index.php` and `http://example.com/form.html` can be accessed.

**Update 2**
If I use both rule sets and send my POST to `http://example.com/index.php` I do not receive any errors?!

So the rules interfere only if I sent a POST to the root URL. But why?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php$
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
> RewriteRule . - [F,L]
> ```

Assuming your `DirectoryIndex` is set to `index.php` and you have no other directives then it would seem to be your first rule block that is resulting in the 403 Forbidden when accessing `http://example.com/`. The above only allows direct POST requests to `/index.php`.

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* (a single dot) in the above prevents the rule being processed at all for requests to `http://example.com/`. mod_dir then initiates an internal subrequest to `/index.php`. Note that this subrequest actually appears as an internal GET request (which is what the `REQUEST_METHOD` server variable gets set to), so the above condition (`!POST`) is successful and the request is ultimately forbidden.

It would be preferable to canonicalise the request and externally redirect (308 - permanent redirect preserving the request method) any request for `/index.php` to `/`. You can then concentrate on matching just `/` and can ignore subrequests.

```
# Exception for error document (before other directives)
RewriteRule ^form\.html$ - [L]

# Canonicalise URL and remove "index.php" if requested
RewriteRule %{REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=308,L]

# Only allow POST requests to the document root
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteRule ^$ - [F]
```

(No need for the `L` flag when `F` is used. `L` is implied.)

Make sure the browser cache is clear before testing. (It might be preferable to test with `R=307` (temporary) redirects to avoid the cache.)

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php$
> RewriteRule . - [F,L]
> ```

As you suggest, this does not conflict with the above rules, it matches anything other than `/` and `/index.php` (when used in `.htaccess`). So, this forbids access to all other URLs, regardless of the request method. (As mentioned above, it appears to be the first rule that was triggering the 403 when accessing `http://example.com/`.) Providing you include an exception for your error documents, as above, then you don't need to add an additional condition.

Comment: The first part of your answer regarding the *single dot* and *internal GET* is wrong. As I wrote in my first sentence this rule (alone) works without problems. P.S. I added the DirectoryIndex setting so nobody needs to think about that.